# why i am not able crete instance of custom String class while i am able to create instance of custom System class

Tags: java, string

I have two sets of code in fist i have defined custom String class and trying to create instance of it while in second i have defined custom System class and trying to create instance of it.

This is neither an interview question nor homework, i just tried it after checking [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151299133464341&set=a.203756194340.129419.201821239340&type=1&theater)

In this I am trying to create instance of String class i have defined and i got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = new String();
        java.lang.System.out.println("done");
    }
}

class String {
    public String() {
        java.lang.System.out.println("custom String");
    }
}
```

In this part i am trying to create instance of System class i have defined and it worked fine

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System s = new System();
        java.lang.System.out.println("done");
    }
}
class System {
    public System(){
        java.lang.System.out.println("custom System");
    }
}
```

Both String and System class are final, so why there is difference in behavior??

Comment: Change your main method to receive `java.lang.String[] args` and your code will work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza.. You should post that as an answer. That is really a good catch.

Comment: @RohitJain this is a duplicated question indeed (I can't find the link atm) so no need to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `main` is using your custom `String` class as argument type which is not matching with standard `main` method (entry point), which accepts `java.lang.String[]` as parameters; hence complaining.

Change your `main` to use `java.lang.String` class as:

```
       public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
```